# How to submit a Scala job to Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have a Pythons script that I was able to submit to Spark in the following way:

```
/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --master yarn-client test.py
```

Now, I try to submit a Scala program in the same way:

```
/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --master yarn-client test.scala
```

As a result I get the following error message:

```
Error: Cannot load main class from JAR file:/home/myname/spark/test.scala
Run with --help for usage help or --verbose for debug output
```

The Scala program itself is just a Hello World program:

```
object HelloWorld {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For starters you'll have to create a jar file. You cannot simply submit Scala source. If in doubt see [Getting Started with sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/index.html).

After that just add a `class` parameter pointing to the `HelloWorld`. Assuming no packages:

```
/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --master yarn-client --class "HelloWorld" path_to.jar
```

Answer (score 4):

It depends on cluster mode you are using.

Have a look at generic command

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class <main-class>
  --master <master-url> \
  --deploy-mode <deploy-mode> \
  --conf <key>=<value> \
  ... # other options
  <application-jar> \
  [application-arguments]
```

For yarn-client,

```
/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit \
  --class "HelloWorld" your_jar_with_scala_file \
  --master yarn-client
```

Have a look at Spark [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) for better understanding.